# How to keep removing values at odd places from a vector until we're just left with one?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, vector, lambda

Let J be a vector having values (0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1)

I want to keep removing all values from odd places from the vector until J has only one element left in it.

(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1) => (1, 2, 5, 3)  => (2,3) => (3)

How do I achieve this?

My approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int J[] = {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1};
  int len=sizeof(J)/sizeof(J[0]);
  vector<int> Jvec;
  for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {  //Putting the values of array into Jvec
    Jvec.push_back(J[i]);
  }

  while (Jvec.size()!=1) {
    vector<int> oddJ;
    for (int k=0; k<Jvec.size(); k=k+2) {  //Storing values of odd places
      oddJ.push_back(Jvec[k]);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<oddJ.size(); i++) {
      Jvec.erase(remove(Jvec.begin(), Jvec.end(), oddJ[i]), Jvec.end()); //removing values from vector by value, not index
    }
  }
  cout << Jvec[0];
  return 0;
}
```

I'm getting 5 instead of 3. Is my logic faulty? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you try to use the debugger? What are the values of your vector after every erase call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove odd positions from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388806/how-to-remove-odd-positions-from-a-list)

Comment: can i simply say that answer will be last or second last number

Comment: From _odd places_ actually means from _even indexes_? In C++, indexes start from 0.

Comment: No, not odd indices, odd places, which is equivalent of saying even indices

Comment: Consider, when you are removing the `1`  on the odd index at first time, you are removing both `1` values

Comment: Yes I tried debugging, values of vector after first is (2, 5) instead of (1, 2, 5, 3).

Comment: @RoQuOTriX  Oh yes.. I just realized that. How am I suppoed to get away with this now

Comment: Another approach would be to find the highest power of 2 less than or equal to the number of elements and print element at that position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ indices of arrays and standard containers start from 0. So it woul be more correctly to say

> How to keep removing values at **even** places from a vector until
>   we're just left with one?

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how it can be done.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1 };

    while ( v.size() > 1 )
    {
        // comment these two statements in the release version
        for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';

        std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0;

        auto even_pos = [&i] ( const auto & ) { return i++ % 2 == 0; };

        v.erase( std::remove_if( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), even_pos ),
                 std::end( v ) );
    }

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 3 1 
1 2 5 3 
2 3 
3
```

As for your code then this call

```
Jvec.erase(remove(Jvec.begin(), Jvec.end(), oddJ[i]), Jvec.end());
```

erases not only one but all elements equal to `oddJ[i]` from the vector `Jvec`.

So for example if `oddJ[i]` is equal to `3` then two elements at positions `4` and `7` will be deleted from the vector `Jvec`.

Comment: Can you explain what "auto even_pos = [&i] ( const auto & ) { return i++ % 2 == 0; }; " is doing?

Comment: @P.Pawar It is a lambda expression. It checks whether the current index of the vector is even.

Comment: I am getting an error: 'even_pos' does not name a type

Comment: @P.Pawar Did you copy and paste the demonstrative program without your own changes?

Comment: I copied just the contents of the while loop as it is. I'm currently a beginner learning about STLs and pointers.. so I was having some difficulty trying to understand it

Comment: @P.Pawar At first copy the whole program as is and try it.

Comment: I did, still getting the same error, and error: v is not member of std, even_pos was not declared in this scope

Comment: @P.Pawar What compiler are you using?

Comment: GNU GCC (MinGW/Cygwin)

Comment: @P.Pawar If the compiler supports C++ 11 then the program shall compile.

Comment: Yes, your program works just fine. I am having issues with codeblocks. Tried your program into an online C++ IDE and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a quite neat and fast solution to your problem.

Since you'd like to remove the 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc. indices on each step, the arrays are **0-based**, you should actually remove the 0th, 2nd, 4th indices on each step.

Here are some observations, that are helpful when searching the answer:

- On each step, the array gets halved, meaning that in `O(logN)` steps you will get an array of size `1`.
- On the last step, the searched value has index `0`.
- On each step (but the last one), the searched value has an odd index, so that it's preserved, until the array size gets `1`.

So, on the last step the index of the searched value is `0`, on the previous step it had index `1`, on the step before that it had index `3` and so on.

We can clearly see that that starting from `0`, the index gets doubled and then `1` is added, so that it gets odd and not deleted. This happens exactly `log n` times.

So, in order to track the index of the number that we should print in the end, we can do:

```
int[] values = {0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1};
int n = values.length, index = 0;
while (n > 1) {
  index = 2 * index + 1;
  n /= 2;
}
System.out.println(values[index]);
```

I wrote the code in Java, but you can easily adapt it do your language of choice.

This gives an overall complexity of `O(logN)`, where `N` is the size of the `values` array.

Comment: That inspired me: There *must* be a mathematical formula for finding the index... It is: `2^floor(log2(n)) - 1`, or more computer-friendly `1U << log2(n) - 1`. Too bad I didn't find [better than O(log(n))](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) to calculate `log2(n)` either (apart from lookup table and hardware intrinsics...).

Answer (score 1):

Although correct solutions have been already provided, the same result can be achieved with somewhat simpler code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
   vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1 };

   while (v.size() > 1)
   {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            v.erase(v.begin() + i);
        }
        for (const auto &i : v) cout << i << ' ';
        cout << '\n';
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see no reference to removing even indices in your code

Comment: @P.Pawar That's what makes it simpler. Observe this: once you deleted element #1, the vector has shrinked and now the element that originally was #3 has shifted to position #2. So all you have to do is to sequentially remove elements at index i (which is incremented by 1 on every iteration) till reaching end of vector. Run the code and you'll see.

Comment: @P.Pawar It's easy and simple to understand, however, it's not very efficient: Any time you remove one of those elements, *all* the subsequent ones are moved one position to front. Including this fact into calculation, inner loop will get `O(n²)` complexity, so together with outer loop, we'll end up in `O(log(n)*n²)` complexity. In this respect, the other solutions are superior...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, where you are going wrong: `std::remove` removes **all** elements of the given value, so if you apply it the second time on the "1" it actually removes both ones, same with the "3" later on. See [Erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom). To see how to solve your problem in general see comment from Renat: [How to remove odd positions from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388806/how-to-remove-odd-positions-from-a-list)